# Couple of questions in backbone.js models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am beginner in towards backbone.js. Here is what i am working towards.

http://jsfiddle.net/pW3SZ/

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            name: 'Fetus',
            age: 0,
            children: []
        },
        initialize: function(){
            //alert("Welcome to this world");
        }
});

var person = new Person({name: 'John', age: '100'});
delete person;

//var person = new Person;
//person.set({name: 'Cooper', age: '90'});

alert(person.get('name') + ' ' + person.get('age'));
```

1. I did delete my person instance, but when i alert why do i get John
   and 100 instead of default values.
2. What is the difference between initialize and a constructor. Does it do the same job?
3. In which part of memory does these value get stored. I know it could be stack, but can someone give an insight on this.

Answer (score 1):

-1 ["The delete operator deletes an object, an object's property, or an element at a specified index in an array."](http://www.openjs.com/articles/delete.php)

Basically as the delete operator works for arrays, if you had something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pW3SZ/3/). Check your js console, it throws an error, because the delete operator has removed the item from array.

-2 In Backbone.js you can treat the initialize -function like a constructor. You can use it to handle the parameters handed to the object at initialization in other that the default way.

For -3 I have no answer.

Hopefully this (partially) helped!

Answer (score 1):

1. and 3. Really you didn't. [delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b2z052x%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) remove property from object or element from
   array. You can't delete javascript object only remove
   pointers to this object and wait for GC to clean memory. Replace
   `delete person;` with `person = undefined;` to remove pointer
2. `Person.prototype.constructor` is a real constructor where Backbone does it's own internal things. In the end it runs `Person.prototype.initilalize` -- place to put your on_create logic